# Forward a web server to another host

Tags: linux, iptables, nat

I have a web server listening on port `80` of the address `10.0.0.1`.  Is there a way I can access it as `10.0.0.2:1234`?

I don't want a HTTP redirect; I want to display the webserver index when I request `http://10.0.0.2:1234` in a browser.

How do I do that? With iptables?

Comment: Your question is extremely vaguely worded - please can you add more details of what you are trying to do.  Are you trying to make the apparent address of the webserver different from the actual address?    You should, at minimum, explain what you mean by "display of the webserver" (webservers don't have a display) and "webserver index" (web servers don't have indexes - web sites may have index.??? pages, but that is in no ways an index)

Comment: Substantially: I want that all packets passing from a port of Address_1 being forwarded to another port of Address_2. @davidgo

Comment: Sorry, but your question is still very vague - does the web server sit on 10.0.0.1 or 10.0.0.2 ?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like what you need is to set up a transparent proxy. Try this:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 10.0.0.2:1234
iptables -A FORWARD -d 10.0.0.2 -p tcp --dport 1234 -j ACCEPT
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

Line 1: Sets rule to redirect all traffic on port 80 to 10.0.0.2:1234

Line 2: Allows this redirected traffic to be forwarded

Line 3: Enables traffic forwarding in the kernel

I hope this helps!!!

Comment: This answer feels like it was copy-pasted from [here](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/iptables-forward-port-to-another-host-844467/#post4165067).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your router can intercept traffic to 10.0.0.2 (and is not on 10.0.0.2), you can arrange things such that typing 10.0.0.2:1234 into your browser will be intercepted [ and redirected at a TCP, rather then HTTP level ] with a command like

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -d 10.0.0.2 -p tcp --dport 1234 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.1:80
```